# 100BASE-TX (MLT-3) to 100BASE-FX (NRZ-I) conversion

Tags: ethernet

Is there a way to convert 100BASE-TX packet to 100BASE-FX packet only by use of MLT-3 to NRZ-I coding scheme conversion by means of simple logic ICs such as some trigger ICs (without the use of FPGA or ASIC)?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen a bridge that runs a 100Base-TX phy directly into a 100Base-FX phy, all the devices I've seen have some kind of processor between the two which makes sense because the 100Base-FX uses a star network and would be difficult to simply copy all packets from one physical media to the other.